# Oembed content embedding not working when link is shared with text

Tags: 7, media

I have installed [oembed dev version](https://www.drupal.org/project/oembed) few days ago and i am happy it is converting urls to embedded content. I have tried to add new providers to test, few are working, few are not.

Anyway, I am using it in plain text (text format) and when I am sharing only the link, it is working, but when I write some text either before or after the link, it does not convert to embedded content.

Another way to solve this problem can be to use [Facebook style micro-publisher module](https://www.drupal.org/project/fbsmp), a sub-module of [statuses module](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses), which provides option to share links, photos, videos with the status updates. These are actually attachments with status updates, but i do not know how to integrate it with oembed.

Any solution to my problem?

Note: I am trying to create a social network. I do not want users to post pictures and videos on my server. The idea is to convert link into an embedded content.